# Manually trigger HTML validation on button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation, constraint-validation-api

I am trying to handle form validation on button click. It is validating the form but not showing error.

can anyone help me in this?

```
<form id="the-form" action="#">
    <input type="text" required="required" placeholder="Required text" />
    <input type="email" required="required" placeholder="email" />
    <button id="btn" type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#btn").on("click", function(){
    if($("#the-form")[0].checkValidity())
    {
        alert('validated');
    }
    else
    {
        //show errors
        return false;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5ycZz/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've achieved this by doing steps below:

1) I'm having form:

```
<form>
    <textarea required></textarea>
    <input type="submit" style="display:none;"/>
</form>

<a>Some other button to trigger event</a>
```

2) Now we have to check if the form is filled correctly:

```
//this is <a> click event:
if (!$('form')[0].checkValidity()) {
    $('form').find('input[type="submit"]').click();
    return false;
}
```

This will trigger form sending but won't send because there are errors ;)

**It appears that html5 validation errors are displayed on input[type="submit"] click :)**

Hope will work for You too! :)

Comment: I'd prefer to use your strategy, but also create a submit hook and let that do the actual submit work. Calling event.preventDefault() stops the browser from executing the form action. So the <a> click event would be simply `$('form').find('input[type="submit"]').click()` and `$('form').on("submit", function(event) { event.preventDefault(); /* your code here */})`

Answer (score 35):

Try

```
reportValidity()
```

So you'd have

```
$("#btn").on("click", function(){
    if($("#the-form")[0].checkValidity()) {
        alert('validated');
    }
    else {
        $("#the-form")[0].reportValidity();
    }
});
```

Comment: perfect! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity

Answer (score 4):

here is the perfect answer

```
<form id="the-form" action="#">
<input type="text" required="required" placeholder="Required text" />
<input type="email" required="required" placeholder="email" />
<button id="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

```
$("#btn").on("click", function(){
if($("#the-form")[0].checkValidity())
{
    alert('validated');
}
else
{
  return 0;
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Remove the else statement. (Update)

```
$("#btn").on("click", function(){
if($("#the-form")[0].checkValidity())
{
    alert('validated'); //will appear if name and email are of valid formats
}
});
```

Comment: i dont want to show errors in alert it should show error in bootstrap popover which is default behaviour of html5

Comment: @ImranRashid I see. Remove the 'else' statement:

else
{
    //show errors
   alert('not validated'); }

Comment: check on http://jsfiddle.net/5ycZz/.. if i change button type to submit it works otherwise it show no msg

Comment: @ImranRashid The fiddle you gave me has the button type="button" which works. It shows the Validation box.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to simply add onclick="return validateForm()".

```
<button id="btn" onclick="return validateForm()" type="button">Submit</button>
```